# How to merge multiple cucumber results into a single report?

Tags: html, json, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a strong test suit built using Cucumber - WATIR. Also I am using pretty face reports to generate test execution report which gives a crispy dashboard. Along with that I also do create HTML and json reports too.

I set up all the reports to be generated in a folder with the day, and browser name. so today it would be like 11-15/IE9/ and 11-15/FIREFOX/ etc. So I need a way to prepare a report where I should get a report which should be a merge of all the reports. Any suggestion how to achieve will be highly appreciated.

How can I do this with generated json or html reports?

Also a thought in my mind is , any how I am having pretty face report, where I am getting a dashboard with name index.html inside 11-15/IE9/ and 11-15/FIREFOX/, I want to create a dynamic HTML page where it reads all the datefiles/browser creates links to the index.html on it.

Awaiting any new idea or any enhancement to my existing idea.